# How to get the common values in second column after pandas group by first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas as below

```
data= [['A','hi'],['A','hi1'],['A','bye'],['A','bye2'],['B','hi2'],['B','hi'],['B','bye']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns =['category','Value'])
```

I need to get the common values in a list in both A and B category i.e.,
['hi','bye']

Currently I split the dataframe into two dataframes for A and B respectively and then applying set interaction for these two dataframes to get the common item for column 'Value'. Please advice is there way without splitting them into two dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

For A and B only:

```
out = (set(df.loc[df['category'].eq('A'), 'Value'])
      &set(df.loc[df['category'].eq('B'), 'Value'])
      )
```

Generic method for all groups:

```
out = set.intersection(*df.groupby('category')['Value'].agg(set))
```

Output: `{'bye', 'hi'}`